# Cannot convert tkinter app to exe. An unsupported module in my code?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

I cannot convert my tkinter application to exe, i am using auto-py-to-exe and i am sure that everything is in the latest version. i keep getting a long error with 'invalid syntax' message at the end:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>auto-py-to-exe
> 111665 ERROR: An error occurred while packaging
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py", line 131, in package
> run_pyinstaller()
> File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main*_.py", line 114, in run
> run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
> File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main*_.py", line 65, in run_build
> PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
> File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 725, in main
> build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
> File "c:\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 669, in build
> code = compile(f.read(), spec, 'exec')
> File "C:\Users\SHADOW~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1grfa48e\Shadow's code decoder.spec", line 26
> name='Shadow's code decoder',
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The code that auto-py-to-exe creates for pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --icon "C:/Users/Shadow Kurkangsk/Desktop/Shadow's code 
decoder/ShadowK.ico" --add-data "C:/Users/Shadow Kurkangsk/Desktop/Shadow's code             
decoder/Click2.mp3;." --add-data "C:/Users/Shadow Kurkangsk/Desktop/Shadow's code 
decoder/closedead.mp3;." --add-data "C:/Users/Shadow Kurkangsk/Desktop/Shadow's code 
decoder/LockSound.mp3;." --add-data "C:/Users/Shadow Kurkangsk/Desktop/Shadow's code 
decoder/Newico.png;." --add-data "C:/Users/Shadow Kurkangsk/Desktop/Shadow's code 
decoder/unlock.mp3;."  "C:/Users/Shadow Kurkangsk/Desktop/Shadow's code decoder/Shadow's code 
decoder.py"
```

and here is my code:

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o6BC_GB9Oq6zptT6UVgn0eXK67xt8xpF/view?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-jLFjrVx3DnfkBF_UAzCE87gOQOR9NfU/view?usp=sharing)

In the case you may need to test it the additional files are here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-jLFjrVx3DnfkBF_UAzCE87gOQOR9NfU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It is because there is `'` inside the path.  Try changing `Shadow's code decoder` to name without `'`.

Comment: i tried that already

Comment: ohh i renamed it also the folder and the title except the file itself and it worked thanks! @acw1668